# Rules for modulo of bitwise xor

Tags: modular-arithmetic

There are rules for [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) involving summation, multiplication and division. For example:

```
(A + B) % P = (A % P + B % P) % P
(A * B) % P = (A % P * B % P) % P
(A / B) % P = ((A % P) * (B^(-1) % P)) % P
```

where `%` means modulo operation and `B^(-1)` means modulo [multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse).

I would like to know whether there are any formulas related to [bitwise xor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) operation (`16 ^ 3 = 19`, `5 ^ 7 = 2`). I thought that there might exist anything like:

`(A ^ B) % P = (A % P ^ B % P) % P`

which is clearly not the case. So are there any formulas involving xor, multiplication, summation and modulo?

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as how xor is a bitwise operation and modulo is not bitwise, there is probably no nice equation relating them, unless `P` is a power of 2, in which case the identity `(A ^ B) % P = A % P ^ B % P` is obvious.